# DOMPDF echo() not outputting text

Tags: php, echo, dompdf

I just upgraded to dompdf 6.1 and now when I do something like

```
<?php echo 'hello'; ?>
```

inside my document, the 'hello' does not show up on the pdf. According to the documentation I should be allowed to use

```
<?php ?>
```

in my html to render text... here is my html, when I render it all that shows is "Test" on the pdf document

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
Test <?php echo 'Hello'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

EDIT: For people googling for this...

I now use the method of capturing the output buffer. I should have updated this question long ago. Now, instead of using file_get_contents("myFile.php") I do this:

```
ob_start();
require_once("myFile.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$myHtmlInput = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf->load_html($myHtmlInput);
```

Using this method will resolve any issues I outline above, though I think after 4 years, most people will have figured this out already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using php code to generate your HTML (so HTML inside PHP not the other way around)
See if it works

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$string  = 'hello';

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Test '.$string.'</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

?>
```

Comment: According to the documentation I shouldn't need to do this. It is also not practical, because I am rendering hundreds of forms with dynamic variables in them. I would have to re-write the entire architecture of my forms processor.  I think there must be a simple thing I am overlooking here...

Comment: Can you show the php code that you are using to generate the pdf?

Comment: Sam I am using your code, except with load_html_file() because I already have hundreds of html documents that I load in and render on demand. So to change it to use load_html() would mean... rewriting everything. I also use a WYSIWYG editor for editing/creating the forms and altering the code in the manner you suggested would mean I could not do this anymore. With hundreds of forms with complex formatting, this would not be a good solution...

Answer (score 2):

In versions of dompdf prior to 0.6.1 the document fed to dompdf would be pre-processed using PHP's `eval()` function when DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP was set to true. For this reason, in previous versions, you were able to `echo` some content into the HTML. While this is convenient in some situations for generating documents on-the-fly it also exposes a security vulnerability.

With dompdf 0.6.1 PHP pre-processing was removed from dompdf. The documentation needs to be updated to reflect this change. You should use the technique outlined by Sam Battat.

(Provide us with morel detail about your work flow if you need additional suggestions.)

Comment: I should note that enabling PHP support is still a security issue as you are allowing unrestricted PHP execution (unrestricted except for restrictions placed on the web server). So we highly recommend you disable this functionality for user-generated content.

Comment: Hi guys, here is more info. I have hundreds of forms stored as html/php files. I am using load_html_file() to load the form and fill in some variables like dates or order numbers. So to change this would mean re-writing how the entire system works... unless you can suggest a way to work with my current html files and the new version of dompdf? Thank you

Comment: So you're using the class, and calling `load_html_file()`? What about rewriting it to use `load_html()`, e.g. `ob_start(); require_once($filename); $html = ob_get_clean(); ... $dompdf->load_html($html);`? The only potential issue would be relative resource (CSS, images) references.

Comment: BrianS after reading more about this yesterday I came to the conclusion that I will need to do something like this. Thank you for your help.